# Different suffix for multiple field value

Tags: entities

I have multiple field value -3 value-, each value have a defferent suffix. For exemple there is a field vessel consumption with 3 value, each value have a unit of measure: HFO or MGO, MDO.
Is there a way to show every value with a suffix or I have to use text field type?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) and create two fields, one for the value and one for the suffix.

Comment: this field is already a field in a field collection called speed  & consupmtion.What do you recommend?

Comment: Are you trying to convert between units? Or are there 3 choices for suffix?

Comment: no at all,any conversion needed, every field speed & consumption have a speed and 3 type of consumption, every consumption have it own suffix.

Comment: To do that, I would create 1 field collection, with 4 fields (speed, cosumption_1, consumption_2, consumption_3). Each of those fields would have its own suffix

Comment: good suggestion, I'm thinking of using it. thank you fullerja